# .NET Core 3.1 SignalR "Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled."

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I've built a .NET Core 3.1 web app with SignalR.

Dev version on localhost is working fine

Azure version on mywebsite.azurewebsite.net is working fine

But my custom mydomain.com handled by Cloudflare is not working and returning "Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled." when attempting to connect to WS.

I assume there is a problem with Azure possibly blocking attempts from Cloudflare and not connecting. Any ideas on how to fix that? I'm not using Azure SinglaR service because I don't need to scale yet.

Comment: Please include browser and server logs in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Solved - needed to turn on Web Sockets in Azure Portal

AppServices - Configuration - General Settings -> Web sockets - switch ON